# copy file using \write18 that works on both Windows and Unix

Tags: auxiliary-files, shell-escape, filesystem-access

I would like to make an exact copy of a file during a TeX run. It is important that the copy be exact, since I am also comparing files and taking action depending on whether they have exactly the same contents.

The `\OldVerbatimCopy` command from the `verbatimcopy` package seems, so far, adequate to my purposes. But since I am already using `\write18` anyway, and operating systems are designed for this sort of thing, I'd like to pass the operation to the operating system. The trouble is that the copy command in unix/linux/mac osX is different from the copy command in Microsoft-based systems.

How do I use `\write18` for this in a way that will work on either of these operating system families?  Can I detect the operating system (or shell, e.g. cygwin) from within TeX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with `\usepackage{ifplatform}` and `-shell-escape` you have:

```
\windowsname      ‘Windows’
\notwindowsname   ‘*NIX’ (when shell escape is disabled)
\linuxname        ‘Linux’
\macosxname       ‘Mac OS X’
\cygwinname       ‘Cygwin’
\unknownplatform  ‘whatever is returned by uname’
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Herbert's excellent answer, I have assembled the following version of a `\copyfile` macro. This macro is defined using shell-escape if that is available; otherwise a "poor man's version" is defined using the `verbatimcopy` package. It seems to work for me on Mac OS X, but since I can't as easily test it on a Windows machine, I would appreciate feedback from someone who uses MikTeX.

```
\RequirePackage{ifplatform}
\ifshellescape
    \newcommand{\copyfile}[2]{%
        \ifwindows%
            \immediate\write18{copy #1 #2 /y}%
        \else%
            \immediate\write18{cp #1 #2}%
        \fi%
    }
\else
    \RequirePackage{verbatimcopy}
    \newcommand{\copyfile}[2]{%
        \OldVerbatimCopy{#1}{#2}%
    }
\fi
```